# Improving performance for many Vue components on the same page

Tags: asynchronous, vue.js, vuex

I am building an app that mounts hundreds or even thousands of instances of a vue component in the same view. Each component has an id that refers to an object in the vuex store.

```
<my-component :id="item1"></my-component>
<my-component :id="item2"></my-component>
<my-component :id="item3"></my-component>
...
```

The store:

```
state: {
  myComponentData: [
    {
      id: 'item1',
      name: 'Hawaiian Shirt', 
      selected: false,
      // ...
    },
    // ...
  ]
}
```

In `my-component`, I look up its object in the store and store it in a computed property:

```
computed: {
  myComponentData: function () {
    return this.$store.state.myComponentData.find(el => el.id === this.id);
  },
  isSelected: function () {
    return this.myComponentData.selected;
  },
  // ...
}
```

The object properties in the store can be manipulated by interacting with the component itself or by other components elsewhere in the app.

The problem is when I try running this with several hundred or 1000+ elements, it takes 30 seconds or longer to load.

If I remove the computed properties, or replace them with static values, then the page loads seamlessly. It's only when I try to load all of the computed properties from the store that I have lag issues.

Is there a way to improve performance when loading many (1500+) Vue components that use computed properties and Vuex? I have looked into dynamic/async components, vue-async-computed, and vue-rx as possible solutions, but I'm not sure which would help in this case.

Comment: I think your best option would be to take an approach like virtual scroll packages leverage when dealing with large lists. Essentially, don't render the component until it's visible within the DOM (or within a certain +/- threshold).

Comment: Apart from what @DigitalDrifter said you can use functional components too. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#Functional-Components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is within the logic. If you have 1000 items, you create 1000 components. Then each of them **loops** through the list of items in order to find the proper one based on id. So you are basically doing 1000 * 1000 loops (worst case of course). Which is not the worst thing - you are adding a reactivity through this computed property! Every time something changes, the computed method will fire again, leading to another 1000 loop (worst case scenario if your item is the last).

You have a few options:

1. Get the store's item while setting the data in your component. This will not create a computed property, so you'll be having a static data. Which will lead to making your own personal watchers for all the data you want changed.
2. (I would go with this) You're having the list of items in the parent component that shows the list. Don't pass just the id - pass the whole item. This way you won't need to use any computed properties, and you will have reactivity out of the box (props gets updated in children automatically).

Just don't add that many loops and computed properties - as the name states, they are for **computing**, not for filtering something you can filter elsewhere ;)

Good luck!

Comment: #2 will require some code refactoring, but I think it's the way to go. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the `Array.find()` operation is most costly. Having it in the computed property means it runs every time the dependencies change.

You can get the array index in `mounted()` and use it in the computed,

```js
export default {
  name: "MyComponent",
  props: ["id"],
  data() {
    return {
      storeIndex: -2
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.storeIndex = this.$store.state.myComponentData.findIndex(
      el => el.id == "item" + this.id
    );
  },
  computed: {
    myComponentData: function() {
      // return this.$store.state.myComponentData.find(
      //   el => el.id === "item" + this.id
      // );
      return this.$store.state.myComponentData[this.storeIndex] || {};
    },
    isSelected: function() {
      return this.myComponentData.selected;
    }
  }
};
```

Here is a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/9ylknr04rw) with a working example.

Comment: You're right. The `Array.find()` operation is what appears to be doing it. I tried this approach today, but the `findIndex()` is still pretty expensive, even though it only gets processed once. I think I'm going to try to refactor my code and go with the solution below to do away with the computeds altogether.

Comment: If one components data can be changed by another, I think you need either a computed or a getter for them to be reactive. To do away with `findIndex`, I would focus on how the store data and the components are instantiated.

Comment: Good idea, but I think it might break the logic - what if you delete an item? The indexes are no longer the same and then you have this tremendous update 

Comment: There's not enough info to be definitive about deleting, but off the cuff I'd say have a property to indicate 'deleted' then implement with `v-show` in the component template.

Comment: In more general terms, avoid mutating the array.